# after saving the add resource form i want to navigate to the month of which the resource plan is saved

Tags: angular

Create a resource plan for an upcoming month
Save the resource plans
You'll get redirected back to resource plan calendar view, but you'll see the current month. You should see the month where the new resource plan was created

```
public save(): void {
    let resourcePlanSub: Observable<any>;
    let msg: string;
    if (!this.resourcePlan?.valid) {
      return;
    }
    const resourcePlanData: IResourcePlanModel = this.resourcePlan?.value;

    resourcePlanData.rooms = resourcePlanData.rooms.map((room: any) => ({ roomUid: room } as IResourcePlanRoomModel));
    resourcePlanData.devices = resourcePlanData.devices.map((device: any) => ({ deviceUid: device } as IResourcePlanDeviceModel));
    resourcePlanData.humanResources = resourcePlanData.humanResources.map((humanResource: any) =>
      ({ humanResourceUid: humanResource } as IResourcePlanHumanResourceModel));

    const startDate = moment(resourcePlanData.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    resourcePlanData.startDate = new Date(moment(`${startDate}T${resourcePlanData.startTime}`).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
    resourcePlanData.startTime = moment(resourcePlanData.startDate).utc().format('HH:mm:ss');

    const endDate = moment(resourcePlanData.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    resourcePlanData.endDate = new Date(moment(`${endDate}T${resourcePlanData.endTime}`).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss'));
    resourcePlanData.endTime = moment(resourcePlanData.endDate).utc().format('HH:mm:ss');

    if (this.resourcePlanUid === undefined) {
      resourcePlanSub = this.resourcePlanService.save(resourcePlanData);
      msg = 'Resoure Plan created successfully.';
    } else {
      resourcePlanSub = this.resourcePlanService.updateResourcePlan(resourcePlanData, this.resourcePlanUid);
      msg = 'Resoure Plan updated successfully.';
    }
    this.$subscription.push(resourcePlanSub.subscribe(() => {
      const alertDialog = this.alertDialogService.openDialog('Success', msg);
      this.$subscription.push(
        alertDialog.afterClosed().subscribe(() => {
          this.navigate();
        })
```

```
 public navigate(): void {
    this.router.navigate([serviceProductCalendarPath]);
  }
```